# Uncontrollable CPU Fan in Ubuntu and UEFI firmware

Tags: ubuntu, motherboard, uefi, fan, speedfan

The speed of my CPU fan it's out of control, going to the fastest speed and lowest without any reason.

I have tried the following without success:

1. Changing fan speed in UEFI settings and setting other speed parameters.
2. Installing `sensors`, detecting it, and installing `fancontrol`
3. Reinstalling UEFI firmware and Ubuntu.
4. Other monitoring programs, such as `psensors`, `htop`, `tlp,` etc.
5. Changing the connection of the fan between cpu_header and opt_header

Are there any programs, commands, whatever to control my fan speed in Ubuntu, or to make my UEFI firmware work correctly, as I can't see the fan speed with `sensors` or other monitoring software...

Here is my hardware setup:

- Motherboard: ASUS ROG STRIX X399-E GAMING
- Fan: Cryorig A40 Ultimate
- CPU: AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1920x
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Update with more info:

- All the hardware is new except the SSD, and I have reinstalled Ubuntu from scratch after changing the hardware.
- The Fan and the motherboard have both 4-pin.
- I never cleaned the fans, because they are new.
- One time, I could configure the fans correctly, and it worked! But after run a heavy algorithm (I'm a data scientist) that require the 100% of all cores, during the processing, the config stop to work and even at 78º CPU the fans goes slow. If I disconnect, restart the BIOS from zero, etc. I think that I can come back to my config, but I'm running heavy algorithms all day, so it doesn't make sense.
- Other times I can at least configure in a range from 98% of the speed to 100% of the speed and it works with heavy algorithms (100% CPU use), but it's very noisy 98% of the speed when you are just programming. The change that I did was change from CPU_fan connector to CPU_opt connector
- The version of my UEFI is updated to the last version, ROG STRIX X399-E GAMING BIOS 1203. On November 2019

My speed/temperature set up is for a maximum speed of 2200 rpm. (I changed these parameters a lot.)

- Low fan: less than 35º -> 30% of speed
- normal fan: 56º -> 60% of speed
- high temperature: more than 63º -> 100% of speed

Comment: Have you swapped fans recently or did this just start happening on fans that support PWM [4th pin]?  Have you cleaned the fans and heat sinks of any dust/dirt that's collected on them [dust filters if applicable]?  Does this occur under any use (i.e. regular PC usage or just under heavy load/gaming)?  What is the fan speed set to in the UEFI firmware (i.e. Smart Control or Speed 1 -10), and what temperature is the fan speed you have set in UEFI set to?

Comment: Thanks, @JW0914 I updated my question :)

Answer (score 0):

So finally I found a solution.

I just **changed the fan conecction to the Water Pump conector** and after a litle configuration in the UEFI everythings works correctly.

My personal understanding and knowledge about motherboards was that, **the Water pump is for a full speed fan and it's imposible to control**. But definitly is not like that in this UEFI. So I can create a speed configuration. More temperature -> more speed

I leave here this answer in case anything like this happens to anyone.